# Change color of divider/text in dropdown menu/collapsed, How do i change them independently of each other in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

[MY picture](http://i59.tinypic.com/357k4u1.png)

in my picture on the left side with the collapsed dropdown menu, i have a white divider line, but now i also have a white divider line in my dropdown menu, and i want the divider in the dropdown menu to be a black divider line, and still keep my white divider line in the collapsed dropdown menu. How do i change them  independently of each other in CSS?

```css
.navbar-header {
 padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: oswald, 'open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropdown-header  {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;  
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse  {
  max-height: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a   {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: oswald, "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse { 
  color: #82C332;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">  
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo/servicepc-logo1.png"></a>
   </div>
   
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">FORSIDE</a></li>       
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICE <b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">Alle reparationer</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Computer Reparationer</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Backup</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Virus fjernelse</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Backup</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Data Recovery</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Rensning PC (Støv)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Geninstallering af system</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">Info</a></li> 
               <li><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a></li>
  </ul>
    </li>
            <li><a href="#priser">Priser</a></li>
             <li><a href="#about">OM OS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you understand what i mean.

Kind Regards

Thomas

Comment: Hi there. It would be useful if you included a JSFiddle of the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi JBux i am so noob, dont know how to add a JSFiddle, but i am signing up now to see how :)

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2 you can use:

```
<div class="dropdown-divider" style="border-color:black;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html file, give the second divider a class name of `divider2`.

```
<li><a href="#">Geninstallering af system</a></li>
<li class="divider2"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header"><a href="#">Info</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a></li>
```

And in your css file, create a class variable as follows :

```
.divider2 {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: @THXMAN No worries! :)